# how to sum two or three big number?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [how to sum a large number of float number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148149/how-to-sum-a-large-number-of-float-number)
>   [“BigInt” in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565150/bigint-in-c)
>   [handling integer having large number of digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559737/handling-integer-having-large-number-of-digits)

I want to sum two different number .
think we have two different number that length of anyone is more than 20 number , how can I sum both ? as far as I know , I can not do this with int .

like these :

26565468416574156465651652464234245645945643526  + 6264635454513215421541412154121541544455412315

Comment: You really need to provide an example with your question. It sounds like you are trying to use "big numbers" that are greater than 20 digits in size.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to sum a large number of float number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148149/how-to-sum-a-large-number-of-float-number) Also see: [handling integer having large number of digits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559737/handling-integer-having-large-number-of-digits).

Answer (score 1):

There is a bunch of libraries that can do this as well as you may implement it yourself. Check this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/) C++ Big Integer lib

Answer (score 0):

You must use some BigInteger implementation. Either search for a C++ library that does that or implement it yourself.
Most common implementations store the "big integer" in an array of bytes. To add two of those, do a byte-wise addition and take care of carry (both generate and properate).

EDIT: Not necessarily bytes. Any unsigned storage like int32, int64 or whatever your machine can handle.

Answer (score 0):

Miracl is a great solution and pretty standard solution :

http://www.shamus.ie/index.php?page=Downloads